# OSError: [WinError 10013] error in Windows 10

Tags: python, python-3.x, sockets, python-sockets, python-3.8

To begin with, I know this has been asked and answered before but I can not seem to get it to work with the solutions provided in previous threads. (I am running windows 10 and Python 3.8.1)

So I have not had this problem before, and I have been working with the same socket "config" for several months without any issues. I started working on a company server a few weeks back with no issues but I performed a windows update last night and now it is not working. To simplify the problem I made the two scripts:

```
import socket

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.bind((socket.gethostname(), 3333))
s.listen(5)

clientsocket, address = s.accept()
```

And:

```
import socket

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect((socket.gethostname(), 3333))
```

And I get the following error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "connect_to_socket.py", line 4, in 
>       s.connect((socket.gethostname(), 3333))
>   OSError: [WinError 10013] An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions

Any ideas to solve it?

Changing socket from 3333 to something else does not seem to fix the issue.

Best regards, Jakob

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem, the company I work for changed their VPN policy (or something). The code works as usual when i disconnect from the VPN.